# how to check if any youtube video is being played in li of ul tag then do some actions accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I have embeded videos inside li(s) of ul tag like

```
  <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <iframe id="ctl00_SliderContent_rptSlider_ctl01_framevid" width="400" height="200" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="border: solid 4px #37474F" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/umG3MsLrcOU"></iframe>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
              <iframe id="ctl00_SliderContent_rptSlider_ctl02_framevid" width="400" height="200" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="border: solid 4px #37474F" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/umG3MsLrcOU"></iframe>
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
      </ul>
```

I am trying to tweak the below jQuery code in order fetch the status of videos in different li of ul tag and then do actions accordingly. I am not able to do that.

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var player;
             function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('ctl00_SliderContent_rptSlider_ctl01_framevid', {
            events: {
           'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
         });
       } 
        function PlayStop(playerStatus) {
        if (playerStatus == -1) {
          // unstarted 
        } else if (playerStatus == 0) {
         // ended
        } else if (playerStatus == 1) {
          // playing
      } else if (playerStatus == 2) {
         // paused
      } else if (playerStatus == 3) {
       // buffering
      } else if (playerStatus == 5) {
      // video cued
      }
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
       PlayStop(event.data);
     }
    </script>
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: while posting my youtube-api question and looking for an answer, I just found a Kashmiri. :p

Answer (score 1):

You should forget about the tag's of holding elements, as the player will not see or use them.

Best is to use the player ID's to target each player and have them send info to a global script to interact with.
You can get a start [HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls) , but there is also plenty of examples in stackoverflow to find.